# How to use my .NET Core Chatbot to respond with answers based on queries to an Azure SQL database?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, botframework

I am able to connect to and query the Azure SQL database through my Chatbot in the Bot Framework Emulator, However when I deploy it to azure it doesn't work at all.

I have created a chatbot and have used Microsofts Enterprise Bot template as my starting point.

I have managed to connect it to my own knowledge base and luis model and am also dispatching fine between the two. I have also managed to incorporate user authentication and MS flows.

I have deployed it to Azure at the point and all the features and Dialogues worked in the Web-Chat feature on the portal.

I have now also created an azure hosted sql database and am querying it through the chatbot. I connect to the database as shown below:

```
    public DataRow[] GetAllValues()
    {
        DataTable Library = new DataTable();
        DataRow[] foundRows;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
          "Server=tcp:<MY_SERVER_NAME>,1433;" +
          "Database=<MY_DATABASE>;User ID=<My_USERNAME>;" +
          "Password=<MY_PASSWORD>;Encrypt=True;" +
          "TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
          ))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM <MY_TABLE>";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                da.Fill(Library);

                foundRows = Library.Select();

                return foundRows;
            }
        }
    }
```

All the features of this work when I test it on the Emulator and it responds exactly as I want.

However, when i deploy it to azure, the bot no longer works in any shape or form, the welcome card doesn't even pop up anymore.

This is the only place in my code that i reference the connection to the Database, do i need to reference it somewhere else also, or is there another issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is a new Web App Bot you deployed in Azure. There are a couple of common issues when deploying the first time.

First, make sure you delete the additional files in Azure. This should be an option in your publish profile.
[image]

Second, I would delete the application settings in the Azure Portal referring to bot file path, secret, and others that you have configured in you `appsettings.json`.

Comment: It was when I first deployed it yes. However it worked fine when I first deployed it and after multiple re-publishing's after that. It's only now that i've added the above to connect to the database that it doesn't work.

Comment: And you're allowing access to Azure services in the Azure SQL server? This should be on by default.

Comment: Yes I am allowing access

Comment: Does `Test in Web-Chat` still work? Or is that failing now.

Comment: Test in web-chat is now failing

Comment: It's probably hitting some weird exception. I would remote debug it and see what's going on. You can break on exceptions and see exactly what is happening. You can also look under channels and see a bit more about what is going on with the errors if you click on the issues under health.

Answer (score 0):

After confirming your microsoftappid, microsoftapppassword are correct, you can try debugging the code locally, but using an actual channel (Test in Web Chat, Teams, etc) by using [NGrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/). If that works, and republishing doesn't work, then use the channels blade in the portal to see if you can identify any issues under the 'health' column. Addtionally, you can add stdoutLogEnabled="true" in your configuration file and then use Kudu to review the logs.